# Some question about metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

Every metric space that doesn't contain discrete subspaces of size continuum is hereditarily separable?

Thank you.

Comment: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2004;task=show_msg;msg=0570.0001 has an extensive answer, with proofs.

Answer (score 1):

**Corrected, since I originally misread the question.**

The spread of a metric space is equal to its hereditary density. In particular, if a metric space $X$ is not hereditarily separable, then it must contain an uncountable discrete subspace. Thus, if the continuum hypothesis holds, it must contain a discrete subspace of cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$, and in any case it must contain one of cardinality $\omega_1$. If the continuum hypothesis is false, the discrete metric on a space of cardinality $\omega_1$ is an example of a metric space that doesn’t contain a discrete subspace of cardinality $2^\omega$ but is not separable.

Comment: Oh sure... I was mistaken. Thank you!

Comment: @Heracles: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Henno: You’re right: I misread it. I’m revising it now.